# How to not send an input field in a <form>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Relating to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660686/after-resizing-image-using-javascript-how-to-upload-via-php-using-post). I have an upload field where the user can choose a picture and this becomes resized (client-side via JavaScript), base64 encoded (JavaScript as well) and sent via a hidden field. I do this in order to save bandwidth of the user (e.g. usage with a 3G connection).

But I don't know how to not send the user upload file `<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="span4">` within the `<form>` tags. The obvious solution would be to exclude the file upload field from the form but this would kill my layout. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure if this works, but could you select the field with JQuey.javascript and set its value to "" ?

Comment: Before sending the form and after processing it, can you replace the contents of that <input> with a blank string?

Comment: How does the form actually get submitted?

Comment: Remove the input before sending the form?

Comment: @EdoPost: I don't think that will work in this case because you can't modify the "value" property of a file input element; it's read-only.

Comment: What happens if it does not have a name? Alternatively put the field outside the form you submit

Comment: I cannot clear the value because this would lead the script to reinvoce the process of resizing and the picture I actually want to have transfered gets overwritten. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Cory tnx i Will keel this in mind, the next time i encounter somthing like this

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008035/stop-an-input-field-in-a-form-from-being-submitted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the following with jQuery to disable your input field:

```
$('#file').prop('disabled', true);
```

Altogether you might have this:

```
// domReady handler
$(function() {

    // provide an event for when the form is submitted
    $('#myform').submit(function() {

        // Find the input with id "file" in the context of
        // the form (hence the second "this" parameter) and
        // set it to be disabled
        $('#file', this).prop('disabled', true);

        // return true to allow the form to submit
        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 23):

Just delete `name="file"` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

If you can add the attribute "disabled" to the input, it won't be submitted along with the form:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="span4" disabled="disabled">
```

You can set this attribute in your js-script...

Answer (score 0):

I needed the form and the input to have a **name tag** so what i have to do was to set a **method tag** on my form. This way, my inputs can be enabled and have a tag name.

```
<form name="form" method="post">
```